# Is there any way to fix outline object from others game?

Tags: mesh, obj

I took an asset from game Roblox and in game, an outline hat look like this [image: In game]

But in Blender, it look like this [image: In Blender]
I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The closest way I can think of is to use freestyle shading.  In the render tab, turn on freestyle.  You can then tweak the freestyle settings to make it look as similar as possible.  The settings I found useful are to set freestyle line set to visibility and edge types.  Select logical AND and only check silhouette.  Under freestyle line style, turn the thickness really high up and under texture, turn on use nodes and open textures properties.  Load the texture from the game.  From there you'll have to play with the settings, especially the vector.  One last note, you have to render the image every time you want to see a change because it is just post process.  Also, set the material for the object as pure black and zing, you got something similar.[image]